# Characters decoding in Postman after GET response

Tags: api, http, postman, webserver

I am using Postman to send HTTP GET Request over some endpoints I need for my application.

In my case, I expected to get a list of cities from my HTTP request: I can succesfully send my request but the problem is that I get encoded characters in response:

```
Milan�KMI"IT

Rome�DRM"IT

Naples�(NA"IT
```

These are Headers I send along with request:
[image]

Could you help me figure out how I can do to decode those strange symbols?